# Transfer my own FUN to nlinfit

Tags: matlab, function, regression

As usually, `nlinfit` looks like

```
nlinfit(X,Y,modelfun,beta0)
```

where `modelfun` depends on `X` and `Y`. I have a function `f`, which depends on constant  matrix (generated before using `nlinfit`):

```
function [value] = f(X,Y,Matr)
```

How to transfer `f` to `nlinfit` accurately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an anonymous function:

```
%# define Matr here
Matr = rand(3); %# e.g. 3x3 double array with random numbers

%# define the anonymous function to pass to nlinfit
%# @ signals an anonymous function
%# (x,y) are the two inputs the function takes
%# f(x,y,Matr) is the function that is called with variable x,y
%# and constant Matr as defined in the workspace at the moment
%# modelfun gets defined.
modelfun = @(x,y)f(x,y,Matr);

%# call nlinfit
result = nlinfit(X,Y,modelfun,beta0);
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I expected something like 
[beta,R,J,CovB] = nlinfit(X,y,@func,beta0,'matr',W);
, where W is a matrix. But your approach is much better.